# Error installing mongodb using npm in windows 10

Tags: mongodb, npm-install

I need some help install mongodb driver on my windows 10 computer. I've tried running npm install, but I get an error

```
npm ERR! code EBADPLATFORM
npm ERR! notsup Unsupported platform for mongodb@0.9.9: wanted {"os":"linux,darwin,freebsd"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm ERR! notsup Valid OS:    linux,darwin,freebsd
npm ERR! notsup Valid Arch:  undefined
npm ERR! notsup Actual OS:   win32
npm ERR! notsup Actual Arch: x64
```

My node version is v18.9.0 and npm version is 8.19.2
I'll be glad if some one can help me debug this error

Comment: Does [`npm install mongodb@5.6`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/node/current/quick-start/download-and-install/#install-the-node.js-driver) work?

Comment: No it does not. Still brings the same error

Comment: If you follow all the steps shown at [Download and Install](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/node/current/quick-start/download-and-install/), what happens then?

Comment: I have deleted my node modules then force installed mongodb. It seems to work, though its not the best solution

Comment: So, at least for the moment, your problem is resolved?